# How is the setuid bit actually implemented in *nix?

Tags: linux, bash, setuid

It is documented in [many places](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) that the `setuid` bit enables a ordinary user to run an executable with the privileges of the execute's owner rather than his own.

However, I have not found any place where the implementation of the `setuid` bit is documented.

Here is my speculation.

1. When the command from `bash`, it makes the `fork` and then  `exec` system call.
2. Control passes to the kernel and the kernel examines the `setuid` bit on the argument to `exec`.
3. If the kernel sees that the bit is set, then it will start set the `euid` of the new process to the file's owner, and then launch the new process.
4. The process exits normally with the privileges of the file owner.
5. The original `bash` process has never obtained root privileges.

Is this close to how it is actually implemented in practice, or is it a different set of steps?

Comment: Yes, it is correct. Read [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, Thanks for the reference. I had only looked at the man page for `exec`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is correct. Read [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) – Basile Starynkevitch